# Create calculator (JS)

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have a line `calc(2).add(3).add(5).res()` and need to write a solution so that I have `10` as a result.
I tried this

```js
class Calc{
    constructor(num){
        this.num = num
    }

    add(a){
        this.num += a;
        return this;
    }

    res() {
        return this.num;
    }
}
let calc = new Calc(2)
console.log(calc.add(3).add(5).res())
```

but in my case I pass `2` in `new Calc(2)`, not in `calc(2)`. How can I change it?

Will be really grateful for any help!

Comment: @alotropico no, it doesn't work exactly as wanted - it's not possible to have the code `calc(2).add(3).add(5).res()` which produces a the result. The best you can have is `(new Calc(2)).add(3).add(5).res()` which is definitely not the same code.

Comment: Yes, It hit me a little too late. Maybe my answer below is right for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have an elegant solution leveraging the power of closures:

```js
function calc(x) {
  return {
    res: function() {
      return x;
    },
    add: function(y) {
      return calc(x + y)
    }
  }
}

test(
  10,
  calc(10).res()
);
test(
  10,
  calc(3).add(7).res()
);
test(
  10,
  calc(8).add(2).res()
);
test(
  10,
  calc(2).add(3).add(5).res()
);


function test(expected, actual) {
  console.log(
`result is: ${actual}
correct: ${actual === expected}
`)
}
```

The `calc` function takes the initial number called `x` and returns an object with two methods:

- `res()` just returns the number
- `add()` will take a parameter `y`, sums it with `x` and calls `calc` again with the result.

So your interface is entirely consistent: `calc(10)` is going to be the same as `calc(3).add(7)` or `calc(8).add(2)` or `calc(2).add(3).add(5)`. You can chain the `add` calls as much as you want and it's always going to be the same. Calling `res()` will end the chain and just give you the number that `calc` currently holds - whether you've done `calc(10).res()` or `calc(2).add(3).add(5).res()`.

The code can be shortened a lot using arrow functions:

```js
const calc = x => ({
  res: () => x,
  add: y => calc(x + y)
});

test(
  10,
  calc(10).res()
);
test(
  10,
  calc(3).add(7).res()
);
test(
  10,
  calc(8).add(2).res()
);
test(
  10,
  calc(2).add(3).add(5).res()
);


function test(expected, actual) {
  console.log(
`result is: ${actual}
correct: ${actual === expected}
`)
}
```

Other operations can also easily be added using the same pattern:

```js
const calc = x => ({
  res: () => x,
  add: y => calc(x + y),
  sub: y => calc(x - y),
  mul: y => calc(x * y),
  div: y => calc(x / y)
});

test(
  2,
  calc(5).add(5).mul(2).sub(4).div(8).res()
  // (((5 + 5) * 2) - 4) / 8 = 
  // ((10 * 2) - 4) / 8 = 
  // (20 - 4) / 8 = 
  // 16 / 8 = 2
);


function test(expected, actual) {
  console.log(
`result is: ${actual}
correct: ${actual === expected}
`)
}
```

Note that since each operation is executed immediately, so the only precedence you currently have is what comes first.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, this would be a way to do it:

```js
class Calc{
    constructor(num){
        this.num = num
    }

    add(a){
        this.num += a;
        return this;
    }

    res() {
        return this.num;
    }
}
let calc = function(num){ return new Calc(num) }
console.log(calc(2).add(3).add(5).res())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `calc` as function that returns Calc object.

```js
class Calc{
    constructor(num){
        this.num = num
    }

    add(a){
        this.num += a;
        return this;
    }

    res() {
        return this.num;
    }
}

const calc = (input) => new Calc(input);
console.log(calc(2).add(3).add(5).res())
```