# Javascript static method chaining

Tags: javascript, class, oop, chain

Can i chain static methods in javascript ?
here's what an example for what i am trying to do

```
test.js
'use strict'

class testModel{

  static a(){
     
    return "something that will be used in next method"
  }
  static b(){
    let previousMethodData = "previous method data"

    return "data that has been modified by b() method"
  }
}

module.exports = testModel
```

then i want to be able to called the methods like this

```
const value = testModel.a().b()
```

Comment: If you `return testModel`, you're returning an object that has a method `b` you can call. But that doesn't include any data then. There are probably many ways to bend over backwards to enable this, but it just doesn't make a whole lot of sense to begin with.

Comment: You can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143808/create-calculator-js) for an example of chained operations. However, I'm not sure I can suggest a general solution, as not all use cases benefit from method chaining. You have to at least partially tailor your approach every time. It's usually something like carrying over the result somewhere, for each method to access. Or you can collect the operations and pass the value through them all of them which gives you lazy evaluation. You can look into transducers for the latter case. However, not sure if that's what you're after

Comment: Yes? Just return `this` each those functions? But then don't use static methods. See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/137999/what-is-the-name-for-the-idiom-using-method-chaining-to-build-an-object

Given that it look slke you want your thing to be inherrently stateful, static methods don't seem to make sense. Unless you are trying to build a singleton?

Comment: ah i see thank you for responding to my stupid question,
what im trying to do is, i want to build a model like laravel eloquent, where i can do
Table.update(data).save() but using static method and i dont know if that's possible or not

Comment: Laravel probably returns an object—an instance—from its static method which holds the data and has methods, a typical *builder* pattern.

Comment: is there any reference for builder pattern ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have explained in the comments that you want the methods `a()` and `b()` to be instance methods rather than static methods so that you can manipulate the value of `this`.

In order to have the static chaining that you want, only the **first** method in the chain needs to be static.  You can call a static method like `create()` that returns an instance, and then subsequent functions in the chain can be called on that instance.  Here's a simple example:

```js
class TestModel {
    constructor() {
        this.data = {};
    }
    static create() {
        return new TestModel();
    }
    a() {
        this.data.a = true;
        return this;
    }
    b() {
        this.data.b = true;
        return this;
    }
    final() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
console.log(TestModel.create().a().b().final()); // => {"a": true, "b": true}
console.log(TestModel.create().a().final()); // => {"a": true}
console.log(TestModel.create().b().final()); // => {"b": true}
```