# Chain method from function

Tags: javascript, math, cheerio, chaining

Trying to understand chinning method, can be math like, cheerio/jQuery like, gonna shorten and replace with my own methods when things get too long.

```js
//It will help me get shorten methods in complex methods and apply to a project

function getValue() {  
    this.add = function(y) {
        return x + y;
    };

    this.mult = function(y) {
        return x * y;
    };

    return this;
};

// not using instance from new operator will interesting

const price1 = getValue(8);
const price2 = getValue(2).add(1);
const price3 = getValue(5).add(3).mult(2);

//not important, but pushing further:
const price4 = getValue().add(2).add(2);
const price5 = getValue(5).add(2).add(2);

console.log(price1); // expect 8
console.log(price2); // expect 3
console.log(price3); // expect 16
console.log(price4); // expect 4
console.log(price5); // expect 9
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. `add` and `mult` return  isn't currently chainable because it's returning the numeric value; numbers don't have an `add` function.

Comment: also manged to get with value or x in the end.
Possible to remove it?

Comment: instead of getValue(5).add(2).add(2).x or getValue(5).add(2).add(2).value()
would be great syntax to use getValue(5).add(2).add(2)

Comment: @RodrigoSebastião Why would that syntax be great? I'd think an [explicit `.value()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76008734/6243352) at the end would be ideal so you know you're ending the chain. This is how jQuery and Cheerio, as well as just about any chainable API I know of works. Without an explicit `.value()`, you can maybe log the value by hijacking `.valueOf`/`.toString`, but you wouldn't be able to store the result in a variable and continue working with it programmatically, which is the important thing, I'd think.

Comment: Trying to understand why I can $(".select") or $(".select").text() or $(".select").filter(()=>{}).next.find(".more"). But cannot create it my own.

Comment: See [Create calculator (JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64143808)

Comment: @RodrigoSebastião `.text()` is a terminating action that returns a primitive, just like `.value()`. `.find()` and `$(".select")` don't, so I'm not sure why you included those examples. They're intermediate, chainable operations that describe the steps to create a result, rather than termination operations that produce a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `getValue` to take a parameter of `x`. Also, your chaining functions should return `this`. Lastly, you need a function to unwrap the value i.e. `value()`.

Note that in `price4`, you do not pass an initial value, so you can default to `0`.

```js
function getValue(x = 0) {
  this.x = x;
  this.add = function(y) {
    this.x += y;
    return this;
  };
  this.mult = function(y) {
    this.x *= y;
    return this;
  };
  this.value = function() {
    return this.x;
  };
  return this;
};

const price1 = getValue(8).value();
const price2 = getValue(2).add(1).value();
const price3 = getValue(5).add(3).mult(2).value();
const price4 = getValue().add(2).add(2).value();
const price5 = getValue(5).add(2).add(2).value();

console.log(price1); // expect 8
console.log(price2); // expect 3
console.log(price3); // expect 16
console.log(price4); // expect 4
console.log(price5); // expect 9
```

Lodash's [`_.chain`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chain) works like this:

```js
const price1 = _.chain(8).value();
const price2 = _.chain(2).add(1).value();
const price3 = _.chain(5).add(3).multiply(2).value();
const price4 = _.chain().add(2).add(2).value();
const price5 = _.chain(5).add(2).add(2).value();

console.log(price1); // expect 8
console.log(price2); // expect 3
console.log(price3); // expect 16
console.log(price4); // expect 4
console.log(price5); // expect 9
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

To make your code more re-usable, define top-level methods, ad call them inside the chain:

```js
const
  _add = (a = 0, b = 0) => a + b,
  _mult = (a = 1, b = 1) => a * b,
  _chain = (x) => ({
    _x: x,
    add: function(y) {
      this._x = _add(this._x, y);
      return this;
    },
    mult: function(y) {
      this._x = _mult(this._x, y);
      return this;
    },
    value: function() {
      return this._x;
    }
  });

const Util = {
  add: _add,
  mult: _mult,
  chain: _chain
};

// With chain...
console.log(Util.chain(8).value() === 8); // true
console.log(Util.chain(2).add(1).value() === 3); // true
console.log(Util.chain(5).add(3).mult(2).value() === 16); // true
console.log(Util.chain().add(2).add(2).value() === 4); // true
console.log(Util.chain(5).add(2).add(2).value() === 9); // true

// On their own...
console.log(Util.add(4, 7) === 11); // true
console.log(Util.mult(4, 7) === 28); // true
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is how to extend jQuery by creating a plugin:

```js
(function($) {
  $.incrementNumericValues = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/\d+/g, function(n) {
      return parseInt(n, 10) + 1;
    });
  };
  $.fn.incrementNumericValues = function() {
    this.text($.incrementNumericValues(this.text())); // piggy-back
    return this; // Always return the jQuery object, unless computing/getting value
  };
})(jQuery);

// Can be called like this, but it's ugly
$('#foo').text($.incrementNumericValues($('#foo').text()));

// Chainable
$('#foo').incrementNumericValues().css({ background: 'yellow' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">It's been 2 days since the last 13 days.</div>
```

Comment: you could rather use `(this.x? this.x : 0) +y` in the `add` function and `(this.x? this.x : 1)*y` in the `mult` function

Comment: Thanks for the anwswer.
I will mark yours if can't find like:

$("ul").addClass("list").find("li").addClass("item").filter(":even").addClass("even").end().filter(":odd").addClass("odd").end().appendTo("body");

Comment: @RodrigoSebastião The `$` is a short-hand for `jQuery`. The `jQuery` function call return a jQuery object with chainable method calls. You can extend jQuery with `$.fn.<CUSTOM_FN>` to add a new chainable method to its prototype. Just make sure `return this` is the final statement in the function. I can add a simple jQuery plugin at the end, to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the above code by add default value to y to prevent the result to "nan" when y is not provided. Overall its a great answer.

```js
function getValue(x = 0) {
  this.x = x;
  this.add = function(y = 0) {
    this.x += y;
    return this;
  };
  this.mult = function(y = 1) {
    this.x *= y;
    return this;
  };
  this.value = function() {
    return this.x;
  };
  return this;
};

const price1 = getValue(8).value();
const price2 = getValue(2).add(1).value();
const price3 = getValue(5).add(3).mult(2).value();
const price4 = getValue().add(2).add(2).value();
const price5 = getValue(5).add(2).add(2).value();

console.log(price1); // expect 8
console.log(price2); // expect 3
console.log(price3); // expect 16
console.log(price4); // expect 4
console.log(price5); // expect 9
```

Comment: Tangential: I'd argue for parameter checks over defaults. A missing parameter *(to me)*  falls under the "development time error" umbrella.

Comment: I have tried with the code snippet and it is working perfectly. You may try to copy paste on the code snippet and it should work perfectly. In general, both parameter checking and default values are useful techniques in programming, and their use depends on the specific needs and requirements of the function and its callers. A good practice is to use both techniques when appropriate, for example, by providing sensible default values for common input scenarios and performing parameter checking for critical input values.

Comment: I didn’t say it didn’t work, I said a default value could mask development errors. You can’t do both a default value and a sanity check for general math since any reasonable default would be a valid numeric value—only if it’s domain-specific could you do both.